# How to plot a csv file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot

[image]I have csv file `Mappe3.csv` with two columns. It looks like

```
   Quartals;Counts
0    2004Q1 ;258526
1    2004Q2 ;205120
2    2004Q3 ;134822
3    2004Q4 ;154606
4    2005Q1 ;244813
5    2005Q2 ;156623
6    2005Q3 ;125472
7     2005Q4 ;11093
8       2006Q1 ;536
9    2006Q2 ;142400
10   2006Q3 ;270221
11   2006Q4 ;313063
12   2007Q1 ;386541
13   2007Q2 ;417533
14   2007Q3 ;423587
15   2007Q4 ;424799
16   2008Q1 ;503836
17   2008Q2 ;485872
18   2008Q3 ;686549
19   2008Q4 ;777268
```

Now I tried to plot the data with "quartals" on the x-axis and "counts" on the y-axis (with code below). It seems to be quiet simple but nothing works...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Mappe3.csv')
df.plot(x="Quartals", y="Counts")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why you have a semicolon in your second column? Maybe that is the reason behind your issue.

Comment: How can I remove the semicolons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define the separator to ';'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=';')
df.plot(x='Quartals', y='Counts')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, let me attach snapshot, which python version are you using @jezrael?

Comment: But I use the same code, do know what could be the problem?

Comment: @Torb share snapshot if you don't mind, also you may try to set individually plt.xlabel('Quartals')
plt.ylabel('Counts')

Comment: @Torb another reason, maybe raise because of double comma  df.plot(x="Quartals", y="Counts") --- try replace to ---> df.plot(x='Quartals', y='Counts')... anyway i will update the code above

Comment: Share snapshot and python version number

Comment: I add the snapshot in my question and I have python 3.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193878/discussion-between-torb-and-feras).